# Error messages when shutting down Tomcat with a grails web app with embedded H2 db

Tags: tomcat, grails, h2

I'm getting error messages when I shut down Tomcat that indicates that there are one thread and several thread-locals that are not properly cleaned up.

My web application is currently set up using an embedded H2 database and deployed on a Tomcat web application server. It was successfully deployed in production about a week ago.

System info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 (dev), Ubuntu 12.04 (test), Solaris 5.11 (prod)
Tomcat: 7.0.53
Java: 1.7.0_55
Grails: 2.3.8
```

`DataSource.groovy` currently looks like this:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = 'myDbUserName'
    password = 'myDbPassword'
    dbCreate = 'update'
    url = "jdbc:h2:/h2db/myApp_test;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
```

Note that Tomcat does stop normally despite these messages, without any apparent delay. So there's no need to kill the process (which I've had to do up until now, but that was because of improper cleanup of my own code -- which is now resolved).

However, I don't like having such error messages hanging around. It makes me worried since I'm not sure of the consequences, e.g. when performing a hotdeploy or when the application has been running for a very long time without restart. Does it result in memory leaks that accummulates to an OutOfMemoryError after a while? Will I get database lock issues? Other problems?

Here are the relevant error messages (numbered for easier reference):

> 1. SEVERE: 
>      The web application [/my-app] appears to have started a thread named 
>      [H2 File Lock Watchdog /home/steinar/h2db/myApp_test.lock.db] but has failed to stop it. 
>      This is very likely to create a memory leak.
> 2. SEVERE: 
>      The web application [/my-app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type 
>      [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@15dd7182]) and a value of type 
>      [org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.BusHolder] (value [org.apache.cxf.BusFactory$BusHolder@7d471904]) 
>      but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. 
>      Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
> 3. SEVERE: 
>      The web application [/my-app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type 
>      [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1] 
>      (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$1@46bb95dd]) 
>      and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{}]) 
>      but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. 
>      Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
> 4. SEVERE: 
>      The web application [/my-app] created a ThreadLocal with key of type 
>      [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2] 
>      (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernatePersistenceContextInterceptor$2@456c0472]) 
>      and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{DEFAULT=0}]) 
>      but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. 
>      Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

My comments / questions to these:

> 1. H2 File Lock Watchdog thread. It does look like the web application fail to properly close H2 on shutdown. I tried experimenting with `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT` in the JDBC URL, but all options (`TRUE`, `FALSE` or omitting it) resulted in the same messages and behaviour for me. I also tried looking at Grails documentation
> 2. A "probable memory leak" from a `ThreadLocal` in CXF? How do I avoid that? I'm using CXF in other (non-grails) web applications that don't have this issue. Is it because of something grails does?
> 3. and 4. "Probable memory leaks" from `ThreadLocal`s in what looks like Grails' Hibernate Plugin. Anyone know how I can get rid of these?

Any insights on these error messages or (even better) solutions to how I can get rid of them are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use the Grails Quartz plugin or the Quartz?

Comment: Please vote for https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5823

Comment: @VitaliiSamolovskikh thanks for your comments. No, I do not use Quartz. However, I have done some research and found origin for most of these. I'll write up an answer later today to my own question with my findings and links to issues (including your link).

Comment: did u find the origin for this issue.

Comment: Hey, Steinar, there's some upvotes in it for you if you could post your resolution to this issue. I have this same issues in Grails 2.3.6, which was supposed to have the aformentioned JIRA issue (GRAILS-5823) long since resolved.